# Click Event not Firing in jQuery Mobile 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying writing an app in jQuery Mobile and want to store an item in local storage when a link is clicked, but for some reason the click event is not even firing. My page is below. I want the event to fire when I click on a team link from the index page. This should store the team id in local storage and then the games page will retrieve it and display the team's schedule.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>PA Football News</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-mobile.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
    <!--    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/connection.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>PA Football News</h1></div>
            <div id="index_content" data-role="content">
                <div id="message"></div>
                <h3>Select Team to View Scores:</h3>
                <ul id="teams_list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"></ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <nav data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#index" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#info" data-transition="slide" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <script>
            $(document).on("pageshow", "#index", function(event) {
                console.log('This is the index page.');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "http://localhost/pafootballnews/mobile/teams.php",
                    data: {api_key: "version1pfn"},
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function() {
                        $("#message").html('<p align="center">A server error occurred while trying to retrieve teams list.</p>').addClass("errorm");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.response = "true") {
                            var html = '';
                            for (i=0; i<data.teams.length; i++) {
                                html += '<li><a class="team_link" id="' + data.teams[i].id + '" href="#games">' + data.teams[i].name + ' ' + data.teams[i].mascot + '</a></li>';
                            }
                            $("#teams_list").append(html).listview("refresh");
                        } else {
                            $("#message").html('<p align="center">An error occurred while trying to retrieve teams list.</p>').addClass("errorm");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).on("click", "a .team_link", function(event) {
                alert("Link clicked"); // Not alerting
                event.preventDefault();
                localStorage.setItem("team_id", this.attr("id"));
                console.log("Link clicked"); // Not logging
                $.mobile.changePage(this.attr("href"));
            });
            </script>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="games">
            <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>PA Football News</h1></div>
            <div id="games_content" data-role="content"></div>
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <nav data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#index" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#info" data-transition="slide" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <script>
            $(document).on("pageshow", "#games", function(event) {
                console.log('This is the games page.');
                var team_id = localStorage.getItem("team_id");
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "http://localhost/pafootballnews/mobile/games.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: "team_id=" + team_id + "&api_key=version1pfn",
                    dataType: "json",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    error: function() {
                        $("#games_content").html("A server error occurred while trying to retireve team data.");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#games_content").html(data.result);
                    }
                });
            });
            $("a .game_link").on("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                localStorage.setItem("game_id", this.attr("id"));
                $.mobile.changePage(this.attr("href"));
            });
            </script>  
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="view_game">
            <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>PA Football News</h1></div>
            <div id="view_game_content" data-role="content"></div>
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <nav data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#index" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#info" data-transition="slide" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <script>
            $(document).on("pageshow", "#view_game", function(event) {
                console.log('This is the game page.');
                var game_id = localStorage.getItem("game_id");
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "http://pafootballnews.com/mobile/game.php",
                    type: "post",  
                    data: "game_id=" + game_id + "&api_key=version1pfn",
                    dataType: "json",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    error: function() {
                        $("#view_game_content").html("A server error occurred while trying to retireve team data.");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#view_game_content").html(data.result);
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="info">
            <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>PA Football News</h1></div>
            <div id="info_content" data-role="content">
                <p>Thank you for downloading the Pennsylvania Football News mobile app. We are excited to be able to provide you with real-time score updates. Currently you are using version 1 of this app and as more people participate in keeping score for us we will expand our features. Please see below for information on how to use this app.</p>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>How do I find scores for a team?</h3>
                    <p>The whole purpose of this app is to provide fans with real-time score updates. In order to do this go to the home page by clicking Home on the footer below. Scroll down until you find your team. Alternatively, you may type your team name in the search box and the list will be filtered accordingly. When you see the team that you want to view scores for, select it. You will then see a list of games for this team. Select the game that you want to view and you will be taken to the score for that game.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <nav data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#index" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#info" data-transition="slide" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <script>
            $(document).on("pageshow", "#info", function(event) {
                console.log('This is the info page.');
            });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It has to be something simple and stupid that I am overlooking. Can anybody see where I might be going wrong.

Comment: You may need to put the binding code inside `pageshow` event after your ajax call. Also, you can put inside ajax call at the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should

```
  $(document).on("click", "a .team_link", function(event) {

  Or,

  $("a .game_link")
```

change to :

```
  $(document).on("click", "a.team_link", function(event) {

  Or,

  $("a.game_link")
```

its whitespace left in between.

Comment: This worked. I didn't realize you couldn't put spaces like that. Thank you!